# anything slider changing position of navigation button

Tags: css, anythingslider

I am using **[AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/)**, but I want to change its buttons to be displayed at the left side of images instead of at the bottom.

I believe have to change `<ul>`'s `list-style:none;` I tried changing in different positions, but I cannot figure it out how to change position of buttons to be on the left side and show vertically, something like **[this](http://demo.gavick.com/joomla15/mar2009/)**.

**[Here is my CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/jDWjV/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/4399/). It uses the `appendControlsTo` option to completely move the slider controls. You'll have to add your own css styling (see the demo).

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    // A HTML element (jQuery Object, selector or HTMLNode) to which
    // the controls will be appended, if not null
    appendControlsTo: $('#nav'),

    // Go to https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/wiki/Navigation-options#wiki-navigationformatter
    // for details on how to set up this navigationFormatter option
    navigationFormatter: function(index, panel) {
        // This is the default format (show just the panel index number)
        return "" + index;
    }
});​
```

For more information about the [`appendControlsTo` option](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/wiki/Appearance-Options#wiki-appending), check out the wiki documentation